# Garbage collection in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, garbage-collection

I have the following code in a a module where I've implemented a dynamic forms functionality using Angular 4 and reactive forms:

```
constructor(private formActions: FormActions, private fb: FormBuilder, private uxService: SygmaUxService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({});
        this.formActions.getForm().subscribe((form) => {
            this.form = this.fb.group({});
            this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
                this.formActions.setCurrentFormValues(data);
                this.formActions.setCurrentFormStatus(this.form.status.toLowerCase());
            });
            this.formConfig = form.formConfig;
            this.formData = form.formData;
            this.uxService.unblockDocument();
    });
    this.formActions.getFormRules().subscribe((rules) => {
        this.formRules = rules;
    });
}
```

As you can see first I subscribe to the form to execute that logic every time user selects a new form, and inside that subscribe function I first assign the form to a completely new instance `this.form = this.fb.group({});` and then, I need to subscribe to the changes of that new instance `this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(...)`  .
So basically, every single time the user switches the form, I'll be creating a new subscription to the changes of that form, but what about the other subscriptions to the other form instances that I don't use anymore and I never unsubscribe? Is there any kind of automatic garbage collection?

I assume that the behaviour I should expect is that when I assign a new form instance `this.form = this.fb.group({});`, the old form instance will be elegible for garbage collection and the subscription to that instance will be automatically removed once that instance is destroyed and garbage collected ? Am I correct on this?

Comment: I don’t have an answer to your question but I do suggest taking a look at some Observable’s operators like: mergeMap, and combineLatest to clean up your subscriptions. Subscribe in Subscribe is never a good idea